# Unable to push a function return in a loop

Tags: javascript, function, loops, push

I have this function which returns an array of prime numbers:

```
function getPrimeFactors(n) {
  var factors = [];
  for (i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
    if (n % i === 0) {
      var count = 0;
      while (n % i === 0) {
        n = n / i;
        count++;
      }
      for (j = 1; j <= count; j++) {
        factors.push(i);
      }
    }
  }
  if (n !== 1) {
    factors.push(n);
  }
  return factors;
}

var numbers = [2, 3, 4, 5];
var array = [];
```

I want to get prime factors of all the numbers in the numbers array and push it into a new array (array)

```
for(i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {    
  array.push(getPrimeFactors(numbers[i]));
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I was upvoting the right answer and disappeared...who deleted the right answer? lol

Comment: btw waiting for the guy who will push back the right answer :D You need to use var for your i variable inside the loops, otherwise i is treated as global variable. Of course apply var also to j, even if j is used only once and the issue here is with i

Comment: Thanks for help. Declaring the variables properly was my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Damien Gold in the answer that was deleted, use var in your for-loops to make the variables local and to prevent your 2 functions from interfering with each other.

```
function getPrimeFactors(n) {
  var factors = [];
  for (var i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
    if (n % i === 0) {
      var count = 0;
      while (n % i === 0) {
        n = n / i;
        count++;
      }
      for (var j = 1; j <= count; j++) {
        factors.push(i);
      }
    }
  }
  if (n !== 1) {
    factors.push(n);
  }
  return factors;
}
```

And:

```
var numbers = [2, 3, 4, 5];
var array = [];

for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {    
  array.push(getPrimeFactors(numbers[i]));
}
```

**As a sidenote**,
you are pushing arrays into your array instead of adding the values contained in your getPrimeFactors-array. If you instead want to push the resulting numbers into one array, try this:

```
for(var i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {    
    array = array.concat(getPrimeFactors(numbers[i]));
}
```

Comment: isn't `. push` not going to add values to the end of the array?

Comment: @2by2 he meant that the function returns an array and using push you add one element to the array and this element is another array. With concat you add all the values to the origin array

Comment: Correct, I understood that the op wanted an array with numbers, not with arrays of numbers. I'm not sure anymore if that is what he wants ;) If he can clarify it, I will delete my post as Damien than seems to have nailed it.

Comment: Quite correct :) I was just explaining what you meant but to be honest I think that he wants to push an array, he wants that the corresponding element of the array will hold all the factors of the element :)

Comment: My suggestion is to remove this piece with concat from your answer :)

Comment: Very unfortunate his answer was downvoted & deleted... I feel a bit dirty for replicating it, but here it is - I just left my original answer as a sidenote. If he reposts his answer, I will happily delete mine.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Declaring the variables properly solved it for me. 

To clarify, for the result I wanted an array which hold other arrays of factors for each corresponding number.